# RSS feed has no episodes

Tags: rss, itunes, soundcloud

Soundcloud's new podcasting instructions state that I should use the RSS link here:

[http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:82914291/sounds.rss](http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud%3ausers:82914291/sounds.rss)

iTunes says "The feed has no episodes."

What am I missing?

Comment: Episodes seems to be what's missing.  Have you looked at the RSS XML?

Comment: I'm not a developer. Soundcloud pointed here for technical support. I wouldn't have the foggiest notion of how to examine the XML.

Comment: podcast available in feed set? http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1209292-soundcloud-for-podcasters

Answer (score 2):

Soundcloud's sales team got back to me. The problem was that you have to enable podcasting on each individual episode in your feed.

Profile > Tracks > Individual Track > Pencil icon at the top of the track for editing > Scroll to the bottom & click on the Apps & Podcasts button and check the Podcasting box.

Answer (score 0):

After you click the pencil button to edit an individual track on SoundCloud, you must click on ["permissions"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHmDC.png) then click the button to "include in rss feed".

SoundCloud has updated the method since this original question so this is an update. I was able to successfully validate my podcast rss feed from SoundCloud after doing this.